# Circular imports issue while splitting a large file into modules

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm John and I'm a new coder! This is my first post here!

I recently created a Python program using Tkinter. The program allows a user to insert some data into a database and create a .docx file. It also allows performing a simple database search.

During coding, it never occurred to me that the source code would be so long, but I had already written it using methods that are grouped into classes based on (relative) similarity. So after a while I decided that it would be wiser to split the code into multiple modules, each consisting of a class. It was done more for readability rather than reusability since in my opinion most classes and methods are very specific to this program.

The problem seems to be that 2 of the classes are really dependent to each other and I keep getting a:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'main_app' has no attribute 'Main' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'll demonstrate parts of the two classes to showcase how the two are co-dependent.

**main_app.py:**

```py
import database

class Main():
    ..
    def create_widgets(self):
     ..
        self.f5 = tk.Frame(self.search_tab, bg="lightyellow", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.f5.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        self.delete_button = ttk.Button(self.f5, text='Διαγραφή', command=data.delete_from_database, state='disabled')
        self.delete_button.pack(side='right', fill='both')
        self.edit_button = ttk.Button(self.f5, text='Επεξεργασία', command=data.update_entry_retrieve, state='disabled')
        self.edit_button.pack(side='right', fill='both')
        ..

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    data = database.Database()
    main = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This block of code shows how the Main class uses the methods of Database class (instantiated as data).

**database.py:**

```
..
import main_app

class Database():
    ..
    def save_to_database(self):
        sql = f'INSERT INTO entries VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);'
        try:
            con = lite.connect(self.db)
            with con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute(sql, (main.id_number, main.surname, main.name, main.reason, main.office_article, main.office_type, main.office_name, main.protocol_num,\
                     main.protocol_date, main.other_doc_passport, main.other_doc_driver, main.timestamp))
                cur.execute('COMMIT;')
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
        ..

main = main_app.Main()
```

And this block of code how Database accesses Main class's variables.

The full code can be found in the projects "split" [repository](https://github.com/sinnec/Loss-Theft-DB/tree/master/split).

Is there a simple fix to this problem that I can't see, or should the code be re-written entirely to make my classes less dependent? For what it's worth, I spend all yesterday's afternoon to find a solution but when round in circles, just like my imports do. I tried to change the way my modules were imported but completely nothing changed. I'm afraid the code is too tangled to be splti.

Comment: usually when I come to this error I just import the module in the function where I need it

Comment: Your code is attempting to create two instances of the `Main` class. One in `main_app.py` and another in `database.py` (and the latter doesn't pass the argument creating one requires. Take the `main = main_app.Main()` out of `database.py` and pass the single instance of `Main` there should be to the `Database` when it's created —something not shown in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In database.py, don't import `main_app`, instead:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main
```

In main_app.py, remove `create_widgets` from the constructor. Then:

```
main = Main(root)
data = database.Database(main)
main.create_widgets()
```